# Loading EBImage in google cloud rstudio

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, bioconductor

I am using rstudio through google cloud. Whenever i try to install EBImage, it fails saying there is no EBImage function:

my code:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
library(EBImage)
```

Error received:

> Error in library(EBImage) : there is no package called ‘EBImage’

Comment: Maybe you are using a repo that doesn't have it?

Comment: It shows the BiocInstaller present.

Comment: The URL that the Mac IDE used was `https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/EBImage_4.20.1.tgz` . And technically it did not report a missing function. It reported a missing package.

Comment: Its the normal google cloud platform. And what I am lookig for is how to get it done if it is not preinstalled

Comment: I showed you where you could get it.

Comment: The error I am getting here is >source("https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/EBImage_4.20.1.tgz")
Error in source("https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/EBImage_4.20.1.tgz") : 
  https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/EBImage_4.20.1.tgz:1:1: unexpected input
1:

Comment: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: I am on windows, but I am sure google cloud is running on some linux system

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do this:

```
biocLite()  #installs base BioC
```

Then do this:

```
biocLite("EBImage", siteRepos="https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/")
```

Maybe the "cloud site" is not up-to-date? I don't think the tags are correct. That "google-cloud-platform"-tag is not likely to really be descriptive of this problem.

Comment: This code will most likely work, but I am trying to install tiff package. Without it, the code fails

Comment: This code will work in any linux system. However, there is no way to test the code in google cloud (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS system) because the code does not work without tiff, which the cloud server does not allow to be installed. "sudo apt-get install libtiff" or "sudo apt install libtiff" shows permission being denied.

Comment: That's the first time you mentioned installing the 'tiff'-package. I usually use the `dependencies=TRUE` parameter when executing `install.packages` and if the tiff package could not be installed then the error message you reported would not have been what you have shown. Your error message implied inability to find the EBImage source package. `biocLite()` usually checks dependencies, however.